# Different base paths depending on Development/Production environment

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I just published a Blazor app on our development server to test if everything is running fine. I set up the server so that i would have to access the app under an address like that:

```
serveraddress:8090/UserManagement
```

On my local development machine I don't need the UserManagement folder, I just access and redirect directly to my pages. My index page for example would be available at

```
@page "/"
```

on my local machine. But when I run the software on the development server, there should be an additional /UserManagement tag added to the path. I set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to "Development" on my server and tried to change the  tag in the _Hosts.cshtml as follows:

> ```
> <environment include="Development">
>     <base href="~/UserManagement" />
> </environment>
> <environment include="Production">
>     <base href="~/" />
>  </environment>
> ```

Unfortunately, this does not work and all the redirects go to / instead of /UserManagement/. Any idea?

Comment: remove `~` in your href

Comment: Don't you have Develpment/Production reversed?

Comment: @Henk: To make this more clear: I need the /UserManagement prefix on our Development server (actually it's a test-server) and on our Production server because we have many apps running there. I don't need the /UserManagement prefix, on the other hand, on my local developmant laptop (Visual Studio).

Comment: @Agua: That does not work, unfortunately. Still routes to /pagename instead of /UserManagement/pagename

Comment: Are you sure environment setting is well loaded from ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ? Do you use the default `WebHostBuilder` or a custom code ?

Comment: I mean, is your base href ok in the html page source loaded by the  browser ?

Comment: I have the standard webhostbuilder from the startup.cs template that was autogenerated. I might have to add that I have a Blazor-Server app, not WebAssembly. I read in another thread that the <base> tag is only used client side for web assembly. Don't know if i understood this correctly...

Comment: In the generated source code in the browser i can find this line: <base href="/UserManagement" />...

Comment: Do i have to add a placeholder for that base-href to my links maybe? 

<a href="base/NewUser" class="btn btn-success">New User</a>

Comment: Adding app.UsePathBase("/UserManagement"); to the startup.cs won't work either...Edit: Just moved that line to the very beginning of the Configure method and now it works!

Comment: Really experiencing some odd behaviour here. With the app.UsePathBase("/UserManagement"); set, as soon as i add SOMETHING to my link, it adds the prefix to the url. For example: <a href="/CreateD5User" class="btn btn-success">Neuer User</a> would forward to servername:8090/CreateD5User. But this link: <a href="blah/CreateD5User" class="btn btn-success">Neuer User</a> will forward to servername:8090/UserManagement/blah/CreateD5User

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I think i found the solution. 
First I changed the base url so that only when the Development environment variable is found, the base url /UserManagement will be used:

```
_Hosts.cshtml:

<environment include="Development">
        <base href="/UserManagement/" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <base href="~/" />
    </environment>
```

Then i added this to the very beginning of the startup.cs' configure-method:

```
app.UsePathBase("/UserManagement");
```

But that alone still did not do the trick. The problem was, that I used hrefs links like that to forward to another page:

```
<a href="/CreateD5User" class="btn btn-success">New User</a>
```

With the leading slash, the UserManagement directory was not preprended. However, after removing the leading slash like this it worked and the /UserManagement/ was added.

```
<a href="CreateD5User" class="btn btn-success">New User</a>
```

Comment: How can i do this for blazor web assembly? This just has a static `index.html` file so i can't set the base differently.

Comment: I notice that for me in .NET 6 all I needed was the first part with `<environment ../>`

Answer (score 0):

For [.net-8.0](/questions/tagged/.net-8.0) the environments part was migrated to `App.razor` file (see [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 7.0 to 8.0: Convert a Blazor Server app into a Blazor Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#convert-a-blazor-server-app-into-a-blazor-web-app)) and can look like the following:

```cs
@inject IHostEnvironment Env

@if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
    <base href="/UserManagement/"  />
}
else
{
    <base href="/" />
}
```