# Override the base path for production only in a Blazor Web App (_Hosts.cshtml file functionality in .NET 8?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

In previous versions of Web Apps I could override the base path in production only (not development) by adding code to the *_hosts.cshtml* file. See [Different base paths depending on Development/Production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289363/different-base-paths-depending-on-development-production-environment). However, in .NET 8 the Blazor Web App template no longer contains a *_hosts.cshtml* file.

How can I override the base path for production environments only in a .NET 8+ Blazor Web App (server-side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 7.0 to 8.0: Convert a Blazor Server app into a Blazor Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#convert-a-blazor-server-app-into-a-blazor-web-app) doc.

Especially 4th point:

> Move the content in the `_Host` page (`Pages/_Host.cshtml`) to the empty `App.razor` file. Proceed to make the following changes to the App component.

> ...

> Remove the following lines:

```
- <environment include="Staging,Production">
-     An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
- </environment>
- <environment include="Development">
-     An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
- </environment>
```

> Replace the preceding lines with the following:

```
@if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
    <text>
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </text>
}
else
{
    <text>
        An error has occurred. This app may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </text>
}
```

> ...

So in your case it can look like:

```
@inject IHostEnvironment Env

@if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
    <base href="/SomePath/"  />
}
else
{
    <base href="/" />
}
```

Comment: That works - except for in my case I needed to switch the two base statements. Thanks.