# Migrating base tag from _Host.cshtml in Blazor Server to App.razor in Blazor Web

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I recently upgraded my application from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and am facing an issue related to the base tag, which was previously used in `_Host.cshtml` with the tag helper syntax: `<base href="~/" />`. This setup worked well, accommodating both development and production environments:

Development: The app ran on `https://localhost:port`.

Production: After publishing to an IIS site, the app was available under `https://server/app`.

In .NET 8 Blazor Web, project structure has changed, so I also want to use App.razor. However, I'm encountering issues when setting the `<base href="/app/" />` as per the migration docs. Unlike the tag helper in the previous version, this approach uses a static value. Additionally, I'm facing a case-sensitivity issue where navigating to `https://server/App` (note the uppercase 'A') results in a 404 error.

How can I replicate the dynamic base URL behaviour from .NET 7's `_Host.cshtml` in the new .NET 8 `App.razor` model to ensure my application works seamlessly in both development and production environments?

I have read:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
2. [Override the base path for production only in a Blazor Web App (_Hosts.cshtml file functionality in .NET 8?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77544888/override-the-base-path-for-production-only-in-a-blazor-web-app-hosts-cshtml-fi)
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#convert-a-blazor-server-app-into-a-blazor-web-app

I have tried using `app.UsePathBase("/app");` without any success.